# JPQL where clause with collection in collection

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpql

I use spring data... and I have an entity with ManyToMany relation.

So I wanna do this kind of request:

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM Data d WHERE ((?2) IS NULL OR d.categories IN (?2))")
```

where `?2` corresponds to a list and `categories` is also a list (of another entity) from `Data`.

But this doesn't work... any idea ? :)

PS: I see a solution with:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Data r WHERE (?3 = 0L OR ?3 = (SELECT COUNT(cate.id) FROM Data r2 JOIN r2.categories cate WHERE r.id = r2.id AND cate IN ?2 ))")
```

But it's a crappy request generated by hibernate and isn't exactly what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT(d) FROM Data d JOIN d.categories c 
WHERE (COALESCE(?2, NULL) IS NULL OR c.id IN (?2))")
```

1. Here I am assuming that id is the primary key field in category table. You can modify according to your case.
2. You will pass the list of category ids as the parameter here.

The above query will retrieve all the records from Data table if ?2 is null other it will filter based on the list of category ids you will pass as ?2.

Comment: @JMA I have tested the above code and it is working with JPA 2.1

Comment: Thx for your answer...but I need to add some complexity now ! In fact, i use "order by" dynamically with spring with JpaSort.unsafe.  I use the unsafe method because i need to sort on computed value (ex : SIZE(d.saws) where d.saws is also a collection) so the distinct doesn't work ^^

Answer (score 0):

You should use two queries. One you use when the parameter is empty to retrieve all data, and the other when it is not empty to retrieve filtered data.

Comment: @Query("SELECT d FROM Data d WHERE d.categories IN (?2)) not working :)

Comment: Shouldn't `(?2)` be like `?2` ? Besides, why are you starting from 2?

Comment: it's only because its an example...its not directly my code :) sry ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better split the complexity.
Have a java help :) the containtAll() method doesn't help you?

P.S: Does Hibernate understand `(?2) IS NULL` and works fine for you?

Comment: yeah it's work :) i wan't to perform the complexity of the operation into the database because it's better for performance :)